# Canonicals for R questions on valid/invalid identifiers and "Why do read/make.names modify syntactically invalid identifiers?"

Tags: discussion, canonical

There are many R questions related to *"What is a valid/invalid identifier"* / *"Why do read/make.names modify syntactically invalid identifiers?"* / *"How to control/customize handling of invalid characters?"* but no canonical. None of the questions listed at bottom seems anywhere near general enough. So is this a case for a big community wiki-answer?

The tl;dr on syntactically valid/invalid identifiers in R is:

- [What constitutes a valid symbol (identifier) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049126/what-constitutes-a-valid-symbol-identifier-in-r)

  - **A syntactically valid [identifier](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Identifiers) consists of letters, numbers and dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number**.
  - Names such as ".2way" are not valid identifiers, and neither are [reserved words](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Reserved-words). The definition of a 'letter' depends on the current locale (may include accented letters), but only ASCII digits are considered to be digits. See the regex syntax `[alnum]`
  - Hence, **syntactically valid identifiers cannot contain spaces, whitespace or any other punctuation ``` ,:;+-*/~``!@#$%^&=<>?()[]{}|"' ``` or non-alphanumeric character.**
  - Names starting with '.' are valid but are treated specially and hidden in `ls()`, unless you do `ls(all.names=T)`. By convention names starting with '.' are only used for internal or special functions/ function-arguments, not user-declared ones.
  - (Objects *can* have names that are not identifiers. This is very restrictive. These are generally only accessed via [`get`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html)/[`assign`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) not `=`/`<-` ... and do not recognise subscripting operators or replacement functions. Or they can be accessed via `` backticks / [`deparse`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/deparse.html))
- [`data.frame`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html) by default enforces `check.names=T` on col-names: ['Specifying column names in a data.frame changes spaces to “.”'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411201/specifying-column-names-in-a-data-frame-changes-spaces-to)
- By convention, names with internal dots: `fac.A,fac.B,...`/`fac.1,fac.2,...` usually signify factors being converted to contrasts, or other hierarchy: e.g.  [`contrast`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/contrast.html)/[`model.matrix`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/model.matrix.html)/`lm`/`cast`/`reshape`/...
- in File I/O:

  - `read.csv/read.table` by default use option `check.names=T` which makes them call `make.names`.
  - It is allowed for column-names and row-names to be syntactically invalid. So if you need to handle syntactically invalid col- or rownames:

    - ...to preserve them during reading, use option `check.names=F`
    - use quotes in select operation [dplyr: select column names containing white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842232/dplyr-select-column-names-containing-white-space/)
  - `data.table::fread()` also has a `check.names` parameter but it defaults to FALSE : [fread from data.table package when column names include spaces and special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966957/fread-from-data-table-package-when-column-names-include-spaces-and-special-chara)
  - [Discussion of name treatment in any other file-reading / file-writing functions or packages]
  - It can be less grief to simply set some/all column-names after reading with `setNames`(`/setnames/set_names`).
  - In `fread()`, if names are illegal or duplicate, parameters `colClasses`,`select` should either reference the pre-check.names-names, or else be an unnamed vector [fread apply select and colClasses after check.names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615435/fread-apply-select-and-colclasses-after-check-names)
- The above command default options can be changed [insert reference]
- Other important package breakage/workarounds from invalid names:

  - [Workarounds to ggplot breakage on columns that have spaces in their names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133567/using-ggplot2-with-columns-that-have-spaces-in-their-names)
  - `dplyr::select(a:f)` selects multiple columns, but if the column-names are illegal (e.g. "1","2",..."8"), you need the SE version `select_` : [Select multiple columns with dplyr::select() with numbers as names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093584/select-multiple-columns-with-dplyrselect-with-numbers-as-names)

None of the questions seems general enough to be canonical:

- `make.names` does not allow any customizing of the table of allowed characters and their corresponding replacements, so if you need to do that, brew your own: [Customizing make.names function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776592/customizing-make-names-function-in-r)
- Hence one option is to set `check.names=FALSE` in `read.csv` [How to replace the “.” in column names generated by read.csv() with a single space when exporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152483/how-to-replace-the-in-column-names-generated-by-read-csv-with-a-single-spa)
- Colons inside names are illegal [Why doesn't make.names() function keep the original names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916178/why-doesnt-make-names-function-keep-the-original-names)
- Non-visible illegal characters in the header row can confuse read commands and result in the default `X.1,X.2,...` colnames [Why am I getting X. in my column names when reading a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441437/why-am-i-getting-x-in-my-column-names-when-reading-a-data-frame)
- `.` by itself is a legal name, hence the so-called base-R "Bizarro pipe" syntax `2  ->.; exp(.)` [I see it, but I don't believe it. Legal names in R, piping operations, and the dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950555/i-see-it-but-i-dont-believe-it-legal-names-in-r-piping-operations-and-the-d)

  - `.` syntax to quote variable names e.g. `.(foo,bar,baz)` is used in [plyr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4) and data.table. In plyr, `.` is actually declared as a function.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that non-syntactic names can be used without `get`, `assign` etc by placing them in backticks, e.g. `\`a thing\` <- 2; \`a thing\` + 2`

Comment: @JDL added. Are `` and `deparse` the same thing?

Comment: no, at least in the sense that `\`x\` <- 3` is a legitimate R command and `deparse(x) <- 3` isn't.

Comment: Regarding your last point, in `data.table`, `.()` is a synonym for `list()`.

Comment: @JDL: yes I knew that. but apparently because data.table copied the `.()` syntax from plyr which first used it. data.table does not apparently actually declare `.` as a function, it just understands the syntax.

Comment: @smci fair enough, but I was talking about standard R syntax, not dplyr non-standard evaluation.

Comment: @smci yeah, AFAIK it only works within `[` in `data.table`.

Comment: also bear in mind that identifiers can be potentially confounded for S3 methods, for example the function foo.data.frame could be a method for `foo` for class `data.frame` or (at least in theory) a method for `foo.data` for class `frame`.